Can't load OpenCV library in Java when executing a JAR multiple times (Windows)
I have problems loading the OpenCV DLL Library in Java when I execute the built JAR multiple times simultaneously. The error I get is the following:
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp\opencv_openpnp15738695246714582909
u\pattern\opencv\windows\x86_64\opencv_java320.dll

The exception occurs in all JAR executions except one. One always works fine. If I execute the JARs one after the other, everything works fine, but I need to execute them at the same time (For other reasons).
I use Java 17 and from Maven org.openpnp.opencv 4.9.0 but got the same error on OpenCV 3.2.0. The JAR is executed on a Windows host. In the code I load the library as following:
static {
    nu.pattern.OpenCV.loadLocally();
}

I tried to read some of the source code and I thought the problem was that the OpenCV loadLocally() method deletes all other temporary DLLs on startup if the OS is windows and therefore deletes the DLLs of the other JAR executions before they can load it, but the folders are still in the tmp directory after the error (But without the DLL file in it). The OpenCV Code:
if (OS.WINDOWS.equals(os)) {
      destination = new TemporaryDirectory().deleteOldInstancesOnStart().getPath().resolve("./" + location).normalize();
    } else {
      destination = new TemporaryDirectory().markDeleteOnExit().getPath().resolve("./" + location).normalize();
    }

The DLL tmp folders after the execution: Temp Folder after Errors

Empty library tmp folder
Are there any suggestions of how I can solve this? Or is there some other method to do this correctly?
UPDATE:
I got it working by copying the DLL file from classpath to a tmp dir and load it manually via System.load(), but this way the DLL files will never be removed and eventually blow up the file system. Isn't there a way to cleanly remove the files after the JVM is shut down? On Linux you can do this with a shutdown hook but on Windows that doesn't work as the DLL files are locked somehow.

I just figured out a simple way to do it. You could just pass every execution a custom tmp directory. OpenCV then only removes the DLL files in the tmp dir of the current execution. I don't know how i didn't got this earlier but this should be a simple solution for this problem.

you can try using opencv-platform instead of opencv directly as it comes with native libraries. You can easily get its jar file online or if you are working with maven its dependency is present in maven central repo. for maven you can add this dependency in your pom.xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.9.0-1.5.10</version>
    </dependency>


Hi @Parshant, thanks for the answer. I got it finally to work with that, but I've noticed that the JAR file is now 4 times bigger, and also uses a lot more memory. Do I really need this to get the library working with multiple executions? I also tried to load the library manually (copy it from classpath to a tmp dir and load it via System.load()) and i got it to work, but this way the DLL files will not be removed. Isn't there a way to cleanly remove these files after the JVM is shut down? Thanks a lot!

My suggestion would be to use the prebuilt Java bindings for opencv by bytedeco. Have a look: https://bytedeco.org/
It is very easy to integrate, e.g. with gradle:
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:opencv:4.4.0-1.5.4:windows-x86_64'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:openblas:0.3.10-1.5.4:windows-x86_64'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:javacpp:1.5.4:windows-x86_64'
    implementation 'org.bytedeco:videoinput:0.200-1.5.4:windows-x86_64'
    // other dependencies...
}

